# DASK : IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, dask

I am using `Dask 0.10` with the latest `Anaconda` distribution and I run into the following error after calling `.compute(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)`  :

```
  File "<ipython-input-8-cd6a1c9a02b6>", line 309, in find_matches
    merged = data.merge(matches, on='url', how='left')

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 1664, in merge
    suffixes=suffixes, npartitions=npartitions)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\multi.py", line 428, in merge
    how, npartitions, suffixes)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\multi.py", line 257, in hash_join
    lhs2 = shuffle(lhs, left_on, npartitions)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\shuffle.py", line 160, in shuffle
    import partd

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\partd\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .zmq import Client, Server

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\partd\zmq.py", line 33, in <module>
    log('Import zmq')

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\partd\zmq.py", line 29, in log
    with open('log', 'a') as f:

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'log'
```

I have no idea what is causing this. Does `Dask` needs to write on the root directory? I am working on a machine where **I dont have admin rights and where there is a firewall**.

Comment: Please include the full Python traceback

Comment: @IgorT. please see my edited question. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Dask needs to write on the root directory?

No, Dask operates entirely within userspace, as does Anaconda generally.  In the traceback provided it looks like the error is coming from trying to open a file named `"log"` in the local directory.  Perhaps you're running Dask from a place where you don't have write permission?